# Can not find KNearest() in python cv2

Tags: python

I am trying to write an OCR program in python. Now i got a program which perform OCR on digits and uses KNearest() function in cv2. But i didn't find any  KNearest() function in cv2 while compiling the same. I already installed OpenCV form prebuilt binary cv2.pyd ( as per instructions given by site http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html#install-opencv-python-in-windows).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/source/browse/src/python/OpenCV/DOC/samples/python2/digits.py?repo=xy-27&r=a2e41c7a3cb6db536b948747872cab71c696b44e)

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you are using OpenCV 3.x rather than 2.x. If this is the case, you'll want to replace

```
model = cv2.KNearest()
```

with

`model = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.KNearest
<built-in function KNearest>
```

If you're not able to do this, you most likely have a bad or old installation of opencv or its python bindings.

You didn't specify your OS, but if you're using any modern debian based distro (ubuntu, mint, ...), `apt-get install python-opencv` should suffice.